# DeleteFile or CopyFile fail with error 32813

Tags: vbscript, windows-10

We are experiencing a strange issue at a client with these simple commands run in VBscript:

```vb
FileSystemObject.DeleteFile(AppLocalPath)
FileSystemObject.CopyFile AppRemotePath, AppLocalPath
```

The script has run daily for years.
Suddenly, these commands now fail with error 32813.

This happens at one user only at the client, so I assume it to be a local issue.

I’ve tried to recreate the local folder structure which is located in `%LocalAppData%`, even rebooted their fileserver holding the source folder.

The files in question can be deleted and copied manually with no errors.

By accident, a member on Experts Exchange reports an issue which seems identical. Therefor, this may be a broader issue.

I’ve failed to locate some *documentation of error codes* of the FilesystemObject to be able to debug. Does anyone have a link for these?

OS is Windows 10 64-bit running the default Windows Defender.

**Edit**: The full script can be viewed [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html?preview=X8LitkMCd/Y%3D)

Comment: How is this script run, is it [tag:vbscript] or is it [tag:vba] running in an Office application? The reason I asked is Error 32813 appears to relate to [tag:vba] - "Name Conflicts With Existing Module, Project or object library". Ref- [What is run-time error '32813'?](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/what-is-run-time-error-32813.829206/)

Comment: Is that the first time `FileSystemObject` is referenced in the code after being set via `CreateObject()`, it's possible that the COM entry for `Scripting.FileSystemObject` is corrupt in the registry or something to that effect.

Comment: @Lankymart: It is a vbs file called from a shortcut. It updates a local Microsoft Access accdr file and a shortcut file by first deleting these and then copying them from a network share to the local folder. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Might be helpful - [Unable to create a FileSystemObject in VBScript](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/0511c9d4-9e92-4f2c-baf7-5428d3b2d44c/unable-to-create-a-filesystemobject-in-vbscript?forum=ITCG)

Comment: @Lankymart: The object is created initially and does several things without errors before reaching these commands.

Comment: @Lankymart: Link to view full script has been added.

Comment: You say "nothing fancy" but that is a fairly complex script in terms of its structure with a lot of moving parts. Could it be something to do with MSACCESS.EXE not closing correctly perhaps? At this point though, best you are going to get is educated guesses.

Comment: @Lankymart: Lengthy script, right, but what I meant is, that the FSO does nothing more than handle a file at a time. MS Access is not open when the script runs. And right, guessing only at this moment - would you know where to study the error codes of VBscript?

Comment: The error code from what I can see is not specific to VBScript, it relates to "Name Conflicts With Existing Module, Project or object library" and "Application-defined or object-defined error". That to me suggests a reference issue and as `Scripting.FileSystemObject` is a COM library within the scripting runtime I'd say the issue lies there.

Comment: @Lankymart: A coincidence? There are no modules or projects here, and the FSO does a lot of folder handling without errors before reaching the file handling. Will double-check, though.

Comment: No, not really. The `Scripting.FileSystemObject` is an object reference so if there is something wrong with the registration of that object I can see "Application-defined or object-defined error" being more than relevant.

Comment: @Lankymart: You gave me a hint by the "missing registration". Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error(s) was caused by Windows Defender detecting a false positive on wscript.exe.

Once marked as an exception, the scripts ran as intended.

Finally, the machine was scanned offline and no threats were found.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the disabling of Windows Defedner real-time protection and re-enable it like:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command ""& {Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true}""",0,True
' YOUR CODE HERE
FileSystemObject.DeleteFile(AppLocalPath)
FileSystemObject.CopyFile AppRemotePath, AppLocalPath
' YOUR CODE HERE
objShell.Run "powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command ""& {Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $false}""",0,True
Set objShell = Nothing
Wscript.Quit
```

Still disabling the whole real time protection will not be completely safe. Instead you can also use `Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath ""YOUR PATH""` or use Wscript.ScriptFileName in that place of YOUR PATH.

Comment: Surely setting as an exemption is far safer then disabling protection?

Comment: @Lankymart it will both disable, and when work is finished then re-enable the windows defender real time protection, let me a bit more research. Thank you adding a new way

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks! However, it has been in the pipeline for some time to convert the full script to PowerShell, and this happening will accelerate that.